# How to make column group in table widget using QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I try to make a table view (using table widget in qt designer)

Now i make a columns but i want to make "columns in column" let see a screen:

```
http://i.imgur.com/OUABoWt.jpg
```

Btw. It is possible that QT designer can update code from class?

i.e

```
test::test(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ui.tableWidget->setColumnWidth(0, 20);

}
```

If i compile program ofc i have first column width = 20 px but in qt designer i have default size.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not have the concept of sub-column. You should implement it in your own which can be done by using an item delegate for the specific column.

You can also have a look [Qt Grid View](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt+Grid+View?content=145913) and download the source code to get a hint about the implementation.